# Django proper way to url redirect?

Tags: django, redirect

Say I had a blog type app and I wanted all URL requests to /blog to be redirected to /blog/1/ for pagination purposes...

Would I be correct in doing urls like this...

```
url(r'^blog/$', 'blog.views.redirect_to_main'),
url(r'^blog/(?P<page>[\d]+)/$', 'blog.views.main_page'),
```

Of course the redirect_to_main function just returns a redirect url to /blog/1/

I can't think of another way to do this and keep consistent URL's in my templates. Ideally I would like /blog and /blog/1/ to just go to the same view, but IDK how to reconcile the template links.

Does this look like the correct way?

EDIT (adding an example of the template links):

```
<div class='blog_sidebar_content'>
    <ul>
    {% for category in categories %}
        <a href='../../{{ category.slug }}'><li>{{ category }}</li></a>
        <ul>
            {% for subcategory in category.blogsubcategory_set.all %}
                <a href='../../{{ category.slug }}/{{ subcategory.slug }}'><li>{{ subcategory }}</li></a>
            {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First,Replace

```
url(r'^blog/$', 'blog.views.redirect_to_main'),
```

with

```
url(r'^blog/$', 'blog.views.main_page'),
```

And in your parameter of method `main_page`,set the default page parameter to 1 so that when no `page` parameter is given,it will be `1`.

Comment: yes that was my original thought, but then in the templates I cannot figure out how to reconcile my links as I will have to have special cases for if the link in the template should incluce blog/1/ or just blog/

Comment: Can you post your template file?

Comment: posted an exmaple from it

Comment: @deltaskelta: the template you posted has nothing to do with pagination. But still, you will need an `{% if page_number == 1 %}` inside your templates in order to detect when to use `blog/` and when to use `blog/{{ page_number }}`. Tools like `reverse()` are not smart enough to handle this situation automatically.